# Can't get return_calculated_values to execute in mplfinance (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts

I am trying to get the ATR for each of the stocks I am plotting (renko & PNF) but get an error. Following is the code I am using which is basically the same as what I found on Github for "return_calculated_values."

https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/135

ChartATR = 14 ###### atr_length=ChartATR
retvals = ()

```
try:
    ThisChart = 'Charts\\' + ThisStock + '-renko.png'
    ThisChartTitle = '\n ' + ThisStock + ' - renko' + " " + Dayte
    # ====> The next line of code works <====================================================
    mpf.plot(year,type='renko', renko_params=dict(brick_size='atr', atr_length=ChartATR),savefig = ThisChart, title = ThisChartTitle)
    # ====>This next line of code does not work (generates the error <===========================================
    mpf.plot(year,type='renko', renko_params=dict(brick_size='atr', atr_length=ChartATR), return_calculated_values=retvals)
    # print('ATR =',retvals[size]) # This generates an error <==========================
    print('ATR =',retvals)
except:
    print("An error occured processing " + ThisStock)
    print()
```

I appreciate any help or thoughts.

Thanks,
Manny

Comment: What actually is the error message you get?

Comment: Actully these lines are shown wrong in the post : they actually occupy their own line. <<<>>>

ChartATR = 14   ###### atr_length=ChartATR  <<<>>>
  
 retvals = ()

Comment: I just added code to get the error and this is what I'm getting :  

Error! Code: TypeError, Message, kwarg "return_calculated_values" validator returned False for value: "()"
    'Validator'    : lambda value: isinstance(value, dict) and len(value) == 0},

Comment: Problem solved: retvals = {} should be a dictionary, and needs to be cleared with each pass

Comment: Manny, thanks for adding the error and solution. Please add your found solution as actual answer and accept it yourself. There is no shame in that plus you help the community find the actual answer to this problem better than having it buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

retvals = () should be a dictionary: retvals = {}, and needs to be cleared with each pass